# When do two permutations commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

Let $\sigma$ $\in$ $S_n(Symmetric\;Group)$ .Let $S_\sigma$ := [i $\in$ {1,2,....,n} | $\sigma(i)=i$] .I have to show that if $\phi$ and $\tau$ are two disjoint cycles,
then $\phi^i$ and  $\tau^j$ are disjoint . Also show that if $\sigma,\tau\in S_n$ are disjoint then $\sigma\cdot\tau = \tau\cdot\sigma$ , For the second case I can show that if $\sigma,\tau$ are disjoint cycles then commutative property holds. But for general $\sigma,\tau$ how can I show that? Please give solution for the first one.$\\$ 
EDIT: Two permutaions $\sigma,\tau\in S_n$ are called disjoint if $S_\sigma^c \cap S_\tau^c=\emptyset$.

Comment: Useless title.  Please write a title that informs other users more about your question.

Comment: What do you mean by disjoint elements of $S_n$?

Comment: I guess the definition says that two permutations are disjoint if everything is a fixed point of at least one of them.

Comment: But that is not the only way two permutations can commute, so I agree with @Batominovski in that the title is a bit too general. I would phrase it like *Why do powers of disjoint cycles commute?* Your call, of course.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's my title.  I didn't know what Ritam wants exactly, so I put this too-broad title here.  His title was really bad: "Algebra Problem #1" or something like that.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: A hint for the disjointness: a fixed point of $\sigma$ is also a fixed point for $\sigma^i$ for all $i$.